# Series solution of a differential equation with a function as a coefficient?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a differential equation using series: the equation is 
$$y''+(\sin(x))y=0$$
I know you have to use the power series form of $\sin(x)$ and multiply it with the power series form of the generic solution $y$, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: I think a better way to go about this would be to expand out the sine to give $y''+\frac{e^{ix}}{2i}y-\frac{e^{-ix}}{2i}y=0$

Comment: Roughly speaking, the recipe is to write $y$ as a polynomial with unknown coefficients, say of degree $m$ and $\sin x$ as a Taylor development, say up to degree $n$, compute the given expression (a polynomial of degree $n+m$) and cancel all terms to solve for the unknowns. You will notice that the low-order equations will not be influenced by an increase of $m$ or $n$.

Comment: The solutions of the ODE can be expressed in terms of [Mathieu function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function). 
On Wilfram Alpha, they can be accessed as `MathieuC[0,2,(2*x+Pi)/4]` and `MathieuS[0,2,(2*x+Pi)/4]`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do some reading on the so-called [Frobenius method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method) of solving differential equations.